# DocumentDb Change Feed event type?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to determine the operation (add/update/delete) that produced change feed entry?

My tests are running using the example provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-change-feed) but I've been unsuccessful identifying the originating action.

Answer (score 3):

To distinguish between creates and updates, you can add a version number for your document. That way, document creates in the change feed will have version = 1, but updates will be 2 or higher.

To track deletes, the best approach is to use DocumentDB's TTL capability. That is, you mark documents with TTL = saym 1 hour. Then you can treat all documents with TTL value set in the change feed as deletes.

Comment: Thanks Aravind! while these [all] work, I must say they are a bit obtuse.  The version number is not great as it requires client side "maintenance" and coordination between the Doc author and the ChangeFeed consumer.  Leveraging TTL for deletes is not too bad since that's being maintained by the DB, but...

Comment: Agreed. We're working on first-class support for deletes in change feed, and are open to considering an improvement to differentiate creates/deletes. Please propose/upvote here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb and feel free to email me to discuss more.

Comment: Great! Added Create/Update "proposal" [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/17709028-first-class-support-for-create-update-differentiat) as requested.

Comment: @AravindKrishnaR. I think i'm missing something. If the document has a TTL and appears in the change feed, it doesn't mean the document has actually been deleted right? That's only if the TTL has come about, and the document has expired. Why would we treat the presence of the TTL value as a delete, if the document hasn't expired yet?